# programming in C with an input buffer

Tags: c

I am currently working on an assignment for my C programming class and one of the problems wants me to create a method to get input from the keyboard with a buffer sized to hold 5 characters. It then says that the string entered should be 18 characters. Im a little confused as to what he means by this. Ill post the entire assignment down below.

Write the functions

```
char *stripCR(char *s);
```

which replaces the newline character, if any, at the end of the string pointed to by s, and

```
int checkCR(char *s);
```

which returns a true (1) if the string pointed to by s ends with a newline character.

Write a test program that uses 
    fgets()

to get input from the keyboard into a buffer. The buffer should be
sized to hold 5 characters and the string that is entered should be about 18 characters long. The
program should indicate whether the string has the newline character, print out the string as returned
by fgets() surrounded by square brackets (so that the presence of a newline is obvious) and then strip
the newline character and print the string again (surrounding by square brackets). It should continue to
do this in a loop until it detects that the string returned by fgets() ends with a newline character.

Comment: It's a not very pragmatic coding exercise. Reading in batches (=w/ buffering) is generally useful as it improves performance, but realistically your batches would be larger (and usually >= than your final storage place) and you wouln't stack them on top of an already buffered scheme (fgets+stdin) but use raw io calls instead.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your professor is wanting you to read from stdin multiple times (4) to get the full 18 characters.

Comment: so would i just run it in a loop and add to the string each time?

Comment: @mbarsoum I believe so. You'd need a separate buffer in which to place the entire string, of course. And then ask your professor to be more clear in his assignments :)